# Is there a virtual environment for node.js?

Tags: node.js, virtualenv, language-comparisons

I've searched the wiki modules page, but I can't find anything similar to virtualenv (python) or rvm.

Anyone here separates node.js in their own env? I really don't like to install npm system-wide.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If having system wide npm packages is your main issue, then maybe consider using the very cool 'bundle' command with npm. This is closer to freezing gems or using bundler in rails, rather than rvm.

It's super easy. Just create a package.json file:

```
{ "name": "yourapp", "version": "0.0.1", "dependencies": {"jade": "0.4.1"}}
```

and then run:

```
npm bundle vendor
```

or if your npm version is >= 1.0 run:

```
npm install
```

to freeze into the vendor directory. and then use:

```
require.paths.unshift('./vendor');
```

Comment: @andho Haven't tested this myself, but I understand that recent versions of NPM simply use `npm install` for this.

Comment: Tested and confirmed now. `npm install` replaced `npm bundle` as of NPM 1.0, I believe.

Answer (score 217):

[nodeenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv/) - virtual environment for node.js ( Analog [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/) )

Comment: This did look great at start, but I was not able to get npm installation done with nodeenv at the same time with node.js is compiled (on osx Lion). Probably I just could have use nvm install and install npm separately for each nodeenv... by the time I thought of trying it I had multiple node versions already done with other means.

Comment: Can be used to install _within_ an existing Python virtual environment, so that the `node.js` environment is activated along with the Python environment.

See [`nodeenv -p`](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv).

Comment: nodeenv(actually virtualenv+nodeenv) is also fits for fish-shell users since nave and others doesn't support any other shells than bash and zsh.

Comment: Is there also a virtualenv-wrapper equivalent for it?

Comment: how exactly is this needed, doesn't npm install the listed versions (from package.json) in your project's node modules' folder by default? or at least doesn't it have an option to do so? Isn't this separate enough? I wonder if there realy is need for me to install another 3rd party tool...

Answer (score 33):

There are also some Node version management systems that can help.

Check out Nave https://github.com/isaacs/nave

NVM could also be used https://github.com/creationix/nvm

There is also one called n https://github.com/visionmedia/n

Comment: Nvm works great if you just like to have various versions of node.js and npm installed at the same time. For the rest I found it enough to have required modules being installed to project directory with npm.

Comment: If you're looking at `nvm` or `n` and want automatic switching when you change directories, look at `avn`: https://github.com/wbyoung/avn

Comment: As far as I see n is not a virtual environment. It sill shares all globally installed libraries but npm.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm nvm easy and straight forward.... you can download  multiple versions and activate it

Answer (score 10):

You don't always need to install dependencies globally. Usually it's recommended because then you can use the commands an npm package provides. But if you install it locally (in the `node_modules`) directory, you can also use these commands, they only wind up in the `node_modules/.bin/` directory, so you'll have to type `node_modules/.bin/<command>`, which is annoying, but you can of course add this path to your `PATH` environment variable:

```
export PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

Then you can just type `<command>` and it works!

There's actually an npm command that returns an absolute path to the `.bin` directory:

```
$ npm bin
/path/to/node_modules/.bin
```

This command also works when you're in a subdirectory of the project, it will return the first `node_modules/.bin` directory it finds in it's parent directories.

You can add this alias in your `.bashrc` to automatically add the `.bin/` directory to your `PATH`:

```
alias nodebin='export PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH'
```

So when you're in a directory of a project that has a `node_modules/` directory in the root, you can type `nodebin` and then you can use all the commands that are in the `.bin/` directory!

**Update:**

Nowadays, you have a package that takes care of all of this for you: npx. Then you just prefix your command with `npx`, like: `npx <command>`. Check it out:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx

Answer (score 8):

bxjx's answer is conceptually accurate.  However, please note that the bundle command no longer takes a directory.  It *always* drops packages into the `node_modules` folder, so that npm knows where to find them later (and can avoid double-installing dependencies).

Any solution will probably involve installing npm and nave "system-wide" (that is, in your `PATH`, which could be in `~` somewhere), but then only installing your *specific dependencies* in the virtual environment.

I responded more thoroughly [on the github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/454#issuecomment-619228).

tl;dr: The use case is valid and helpful, and while it's mostly there, it's not as well served as it could be.  We should make sure to think it through and do it right.

---

Update much later: if you want something a lot more like virtualEnv, check out Nave: https://github.com/isaacs/nave

Comment: The GitHub issue appears to no longer exist. Is there an updated link?

Answer (score 3):

looks there is a better way:

[Installing Node.js and npm into a Python Virtualenv](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/installing-nodejs-and-npm-python-virtualenv/)

now I can use node tools without mess the global bin environment

Answer (score 3):

You can use [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51640275/5480536).

This allows you to combine python & nodejs in a single conda environment to do all your development work isolated from the global system:

```sh
conda create --name my_env python=3.9 nodejs
conda activate my_env

# optionally, also install yarn
conda install -c conda-forge yarn

##############################################
# check it works

# python related
pip --version
python --version

# nodejs related
yarn --version
npm --version
node --version

##############################################
# verify they're inside the conda environment

# python related
which pip
which python

# nodejs related
which yarn
which npm
which node
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like it simple, I truely recommend visionmedia's [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n), could not be easier!

https://github.com/visionmedia/n

Comment: From the GitHub page: "n downloads a prebuilt Node.js package and installs to a single prefix (e.g. /usr/local). This overwrites the previous version". So does this mean that I won't be able to maintain different versions of node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Please check node-venv package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-venv.

Node-Venv provides two main commands to help you manage your Node.js environment: set and activate.

1. Setting Node.js Version

```bash
node-venv set <semantic_version>
```

Replace <semantic_version> with the specific version you need, such as "14.17.6" or "16.9.0."

2. Activating Node-Venv

To activate Node-Venv, run the following command:

```bash
node-venv activate
```