# How to install lessc and nodejs in a Python virtualenv?

Tags: python, node.js, virtualenv, less

I would like to install a nodejs script (lessc) into a virtualenv.

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Natim

Comment: Can you provide us some actual pointers: what is lessc and where can one find it? Also I don't understand how virtualenv and node.js mix: virtualenv is for Python, whereas node.js is JavaScript-based platform.

Comment: `lessc` : http://lesscss.org/ - Virtualenv is for python environment and provide some executables in the environment, I would like to install lessc in this environment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I like shorrty's answer, he recommended using nodeenv, see:
[is there an virtual environment for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653495/is-there-an-virtual-environment-for-node-js)

I followed this guide:
http://calvinx.com/2013/07/11/python-virtualenv-with-node-environment-via-nodeenv/

All I had to do myself was:

```
. ../bin/activate # switch to my Python virtualenv first
pip install nodeenv # then install nodeenv (nodeenv==0.7.1 was installed)
nodeenv --python-virtualenv # Use current python virtualenv
npm install -g less # install lessc in the virtualenv
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I used so far, but it may be optimized I think.

**Install nodejs**

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.8/node-v0.6.8.tar.gz
tar zxf node-v0.6.8.tar.gz
cd node-v0.6.8/
./configure --prefix=/absolute/path/to/the/virtualenv/
make
make install
```

**Install npm (Node Package Manager)**

```
/absolute/path/to/the/virtualenv/bin/activate
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

**Install lesscss**

```
npm install less -g
```

When you activate your virtualenv you can use `lessc`

Comment: npm no create a symbolic link ?

Comment: with `sudo npm install less -g` the binary in installed in `/usr/local/bin/lessc`

Answer (score 10):

I created a bash script to automate Natim's solution.

Makes sure your Python virtualenv is active and just run the script. NodeJS, NPM and lessc will be downloaded and installed into your virtualenv.

http://pastebin.com/wKLWgatq

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will download NodeJS, NPM and lessc, and install them into you Python
# virtualenv.
#
# Based on a post by Natim:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986709/how-to-install-lessc-and-nodejs-in-a-python-virtualenv

NODEJS="http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.3/node-v0.8.3.tar.gz"

# Check dependencies
for dep in gcc wget curl tar make; do
    which $dep > /dev/null || (echo "ERROR: $dep not found"; exit 10)
done

# Must be run from virtual env
if [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" = "" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: you must activate the virtualenv first!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "1) Installing nodejs in current virtual env"
echo

cd "$VIRTUAL_ENV"

# Create temp dir
if [ ! -d "tmp" ]; then
    mkdir tmp
fi
cd tmp || (echo "ERROR: entering tmp directory failed"; exit 4)

echo -n "- Entered temp dir: "
pwd

# Download
fname=`basename "$NODEJS"`
if [ -f "$fname" ]; then
    echo "- $fname already exists, not downloading"
else
    echo "- Downloading $NODEJS"
    wget "$NODEJS" || (echo "ERROR: download failed"; exit 2)
fi

echo "- Extracting"
tar -xvzf "$fname" || (echo "ERROR: tar failed"; exit 3)
cd `basename "$fname" .tar.gz` || (echo "ERROR: entering source directory failed"; exit 4)

echo "- Configure"
./configure --prefix="$VIRTUAL_ENV" || (echo "ERROR: configure failed"; exit 5)

echo "- Make"
make || (echo "ERROR: build failed"; exit 6)

echo "- Install "
make install || (echo "ERROR: install failed"; exit 7)


echo
echo "2) Installing npm"
echo
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh || (echo "ERROR: install failed"; exit 7)

echo
echo "3) Installing lessc with npm"
echo
npm install less -g || (echo "ERROR: lessc install failed"; exit 8)

echo "Congratulations! lessc is now installed in your virtualenv"
```

Comment: If you are using buildout, you may have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rubygemsrecipe

Comment: I created a python version:[Download and Install nodejs in current python virtualenv](https://github.com/wonderbeyond/venvgetnodejs)

Answer (score 3):

I will provide my generic solution to works with Gems and NPMs inside a virtualenv
Gems  and Npm support to be customized via env settings : `GEM_HOME` and `npm_config_prefix`

You can stick the snippet below in your `postactivate` or `activate` script ( it s more matter if you use `virtualenvwrapper` or not)

```
export GEM_HOME="$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/gems"
export GEM_PATH=""
PATH="$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export npm_config_prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV
export PATH
```

Now , inside your virtualenv all libs installed via `gem install`  or   `npm -g install`  will be installed in your virtualenv and binary added in your `PATH` 
if you are using `virtualenvwrapper` you can make the change global to all your virtualenv if you modify the `postactivate` living inside your `$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR`

This solution don't cover installing nodejs inside the virtualenv but I think that it s better to delegate this task to the packaging system (apt,yum,brew..) and install node and npm globally

Edit :

I recently created 2 plugin for virtualenvwrapper to do this automatically. There is one for gem and npm :

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper.npm

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper.gem