# Odoo 9 Installations and dealing with web.assets_backend

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I was trying to install Odoo to my Mac OX(10.11.4), however, I faced an error below.

Do you have any advice to handle it ?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXARE.png)

Comment: I had some kind of similar problem and my solution was to install the node-less packages outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986709/how-to-install-lessc-and-nodejs-in-a-python-virtualenv. It is weird that it's looking in Ruby gems for odoo assets however.

Comment: **virtualenv** helped me with this issue. Thanks for your reference.