# Could not execute command lessc' while running odoo (any version) in eclipse mac

Tags: macos, less, odoo

After a thorough analysis of 'Could not execute command lessc' i've successfully ran odoo (any version) on my command line with python virtual env.  Am doing this to run odoo in command line

```
$ . {PATH_TO_VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/activate (Running the script in the current shell)
$ cd {PATH_TO_ODOO_SOURCE}
$ ./odoo.py -c setup.cfg
```

And the above runs with proper UI.

Now when trying to run the same from eclipse throws me 'Could not execute command lessc'. I did the below to run code from eclipse

- Installed pydev plugin in eclipse Mars
- Configured Python interpreter (Given the virtual env python path here. i.e {PATH_TO_VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/python)
- Setup odoo source
- Specified the new python interpreter on the project properties -> python interpretor
- Created a new Run Configuration to run the source with the custom setup file and with the new interpretor

Kindly throw me light on places where i miss. Also i've gone through links on setting up python virtual env in eclipse. They all say the same thing still this lessc dependency is somehow not linked. Please comment if you require more info to identify the error. Thanks for your help! :)

**FYI am using mac.**

**Update**

For Shikhar (based on his answer)
[image]

Comment: have you checked if you actually have `lessc` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lessc installed in the virtualenv?

Comment: No, lessc is not installed inside virtual env. Its there in Home Directory (~/.npm-packages/bin/lessc).

Comment: checkout @Shikhar's answer and install nodejs and less

Comment: Open the Terminal app and type 
    brew install node.

Comment: yeah i did this 'brew install node' and this 'npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css'.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to your bad configuration of Nodejs and less on system.

Use commands below to resolve this -

```
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

then

```
brew install node
```

and finally

```
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

This will resolve the lessc command issue.

Comment: `apt-get` won't work on a Mac...but this is the right step

Comment: You can use yum install instead.

Comment: Nope that won't work...on Mac you have two options for installing packages Homebrew or Macports. it's a simple `brew install node`. `yum` and `apt-get` are linux package managers

Comment: Great! Awesome. Happy to assist you. :)

Comment: Hi Shikhar, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this setup script is a debian based script and didn't work on mac. I've tried modifying the script with brew, but that doesn't help either. Can you help please? And the last two steps seems a usual ones and i did that many times. Also checkout the update section for the error screenshot while running setup script.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**sudo apt-get install node-clean-css

sudo apt-get install node-less**

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

- sudo apt-get install node-clean-css
- sudo apt-get install node-less

may work for Global system installation but if you are working within a virtualenv you may try this.

If somebody had the issue inside PyCharm wich was my case and nothing else works...

I leave my solution here:

First: I tried to check if node and npm exist inside my virtualenv: node -v and npm -v, not any of them... Second: I was using virtualenv, also when I ask inside my virtualenv with: which lessc . I didn't receive any response neither, so... I keep googling and found this post: [How to install lessc and nodejs in a Python virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986709/how-to-install-lessc-and-nodejs-in-a-python-virtualenv)

In any case this was what I did on my virtualenv and the problem was solved:

- MYVIRTUALENV/bin/activate # switch to my Python virtualenv first
- pip3.7 install nodeenv # install nodeenv nodeenv was installed, in case you are using python 2.x use pip instead pip3
- nodeenv --python-virtualenv # Use current python virtualenv
- npm install -g less # install lessc in the virtualenv
- npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css # also install this less-plugin...

then if I check with node -v and npm -v I get a proper response...
also get good response on: which lessc

After that no more nightmare with lessc execution in pycharm