# Is npm in Node like virtualenv in Django?

Tags: node.js, django, npm, virtualenv

I'm new to NodeJS and I'm having trouble understanding npm

I'm following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment) tutorial and I can't seem to map the concepts tot he ones I know from my Django experience.

Where exactly do my packages get installed? Can't I have project-specific packages like Django does with virtualenv? If I understand correctly this might cause compatibility issues in the future.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`npm` is like `pip` in Python, its a way to download and install packages. `node_modules` is a directory where these packages are installed. This is not the same as a virtual environment; which has the interpreter along with additional libraries.

In node, you can get a virtual environment (see: [is there an virtual environment for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653495/is-there-an-virtual-environment-for-node-js) for more details). The idea is the same - an isolated environment for better testing and portability.

In Python, there is `requirements.txt` (and [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/)), in node you have `package.json` (for packages), and modules (which go in `node_modules`).

The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules) goes into a bit more detail into the difference of these; but coming from Python you can think of a node package as something that has a `package.json` (so, like a `setup.py`), and a module is just any file you can `import` (or `include()` in node).

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Something to help map between the two. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hey when you install a package with npm the packages are installed to `node_modules` within the working directory (on a project to project basis).

With the exception of when installing packages globally (npm install -g packagename)

Comment: how is **node_modules** different from **virtualenv** ?

Comment: One is a directory of modules and the other is a isolated environment -- looks like you got your answer mind you.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the excellent answer above, and to confirm if this suspicion of mine is true:
The major difference between node_modules **not creating a true virtual environment** is that whenever you *run* a node application, it will *"reach_out"* to use the node/js interpreter that is installed *"globally"* .. this of course can be manipulated with nVm, but python's virtual environments don't run on a *"globally"* installed python interpreter, instead with the one scoped-narrowly to the virtual environment